Calculating torque in a differential planetary gear train
If I have a planetary gear set in which there are two inputs (sun and ring) and they combine to a single output on the planet carrier how can I find the amount of torque/angular speed of the output? Assuming that the sun and ring angular speeds and torques are different? How does this change if the ring and suns turn in opposing directions?
I’m asking because I cannot find any source for equations or explanations that do not inherently assume that one of the members is fixed in place. Thanks in advance!

Many links to explanations using Google... this is but one: https://www.tec-science.com/mechanical-power-transmission/planetary-gear/transmission-ratios-of-planetary-gears-willis-equation/

Follow the energy.

The general relationship in a planetary gear is this:
$$\omega_C= \frac{R_s\omega_s + R_r\omega_r}{R_s + R_r}$$

$R_s= \ $radius of sun gear
$R_r= \ $radius of ring gear
$\omega_c= \ $palnet carrier angular speed
$\omega_s= \ $ angular speed of sun gear
$\omega_r= \ $angular speed of ring gear

The torque of the planet carrier is:
$$T_c=T_s+T_r$$

$T_c = \ $ Torque of planet carrier
$T_s= \ $Torque of sun gear
$T_r= \ $Torque of ring gear

